# How to join 2 columns from same dataframe, but taking rows a to d from column 1 and m to p from column 2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried several ways but so far I can't get the result.

I want to get `Col_C` which is a combination from `Col_A`(rows from index 0 to 5) and then `Col_B` (rows from 6 to 10)

```
Index   Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
0   1   2   1
1   1   3   1
2   1   6   1
3   1   3   1
4   1   9   1
5   1   3   1
6   1   2   2
7   1   4   4
8   1   6   6
9   1   7   7
10  1   1   1
```

I have tried something like this:

```
df['Col_A'] = pd.concat(df['Col_A'].iloc[0:5], df['Col_B'].iloc[5:10])
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you
>   passed an object of type "Series"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a df:

```
    Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
0       1      2      3
1       1      2      3
2       1      2      3
3       1      2      3
4       1      2      3
5       1      2      3
6       1      2      3
7       1      2      3
8       1      2      3
9       1      2      3
10      1      2      3
```

Do:

```
df['Col_C'] = pd.concat((df['Col_A'].iloc[:6], df['Col_B'].iloc[6:]))
```

Out:

```
    Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
0       1      2      1
1       1      2      1
2       1      2      1
3       1      2      1
4       1      2      1
5       1      2      1
6       1      2      2
7       1      2      2
8       1      2      2
9       1      2      2
10      1      2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]*11, 'b':[2,3,6,3,9,3,2,4,6,7,1]})

x = list(df.loc[:5,'a']) #  + df.iloc[6:,'b']
x.extend(list(df.loc[6:,'b']))
df['c'] = x
print(df)
```

**Alternat solution**: using `np.where`

```
df['c'] = np.where(df.index < 6, df['a'], df['b'])
```

Comment: The alternate solution worked fine for me thank you!

Also I got another way to do this, I like it because it gives you the "slice" alternative, so you can choose which rows from which column you want to combine together:

df['c'] = pd.concat([df.['a'].iloc[row1:row5].append(df.['b'].iloc[row5:row10])])